# please help me to choose correct meanining of "bank" in "I bank it in"

Tags: meaning

The text is:

> I covered for Ashley at dinner, even though I didn't know where she was. Later, when Sam and I were shooting baskets outside, I said, "You think Ashley and I can camp out over at the Morris farm Thursday? We have Friday off from school." His shot clunked off the rim, giving me an easy basket. **I banked it in** and turned to him. "Supposed to be warm".

In the dictionary there is 3 meaning of "bank" and I don't know which to choose for that case.

Comment: M-W dictionary definition 3b  *to bounce (a ball or shot) off a surface (such as a backboard) into or toward a goal* - example: ***bank in a rebound***.

Comment: In the cited context, it's equivalent to *I **bounced / batted / punched / knocked / smacked / thumped / smacked** the ball into the basket*. I doubt many readers would notice or care one way or the other whether the ball bounced off a "backplate" or wall behind the basket before going in, or just dropped straight down.